# Entity Framework conventions and viewmodels

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Working on a bookstore project; I made a controller for reviews which created the basic CRUD functions and on the create view a drop drown list was created based on BookID however when I run my application the ddl is displaying Title rather than BookID. BookID is a foreign key on the reviews table pointing back to the book table and Title is not mentioned on the review table at all.

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookID, "BookID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("BookID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

What convention is this following? 
Can we use this access multiple models in one view without using a viewmodel?

more info: it looked like we could use db.model.property to get whatever property we wanted across different models in a list and we thought this would work without a view model as a work around.

Comment: in the ViewData you pass the selectlist which specifies the title of the book table should be used. [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/examining-how-aspnet-mvc-scaffolds-the-dropdownlist-helper) should help you understand about dropdownlists.

Comment: @Vini on a view can we reference multiple models or is the model to controller ratio strictly 1:1?

Comment: in a view you can refer to multiple models using viewmodels.